# JS form validation / new element is created when it shouldnt be

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js and for learning purposes I'm creting an application, where you can add and delete comments. I added a validation on the text input field and it displays an error when you try to submit an empty comment. Error message appears as it should, but the li element still gets created, when it shouldnt. It should only be added when the input is not empty. Can anyone help me with identifying my mistake?

```js
let form = document.getElementById('form');
let commentList = document.getElementById('allComments');
const errorElement = document.getElementById('error');

// form submit event
form.addEventListener('submit', addComment);

// delete comments
commentList.addEventListener('click', removeComment);
// 

// add comment to the list
function addComment(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // get input value
    let newComment = document.getElementById('comment').value;

    // create new li element
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    // add a class
    li.className = 'list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between';
    // add a text node with input value
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newComment));

    // create delete button element
    let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

    // add classes on delete button
    deleteButton.className = 'btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete';

    // append text node
    deleteButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode('X'));

    // append button to li
    li.appendChild(deleteButton);

    // append li to list
    commentList.appendChild(li);

    // add error text if input field is empty when submitting
    let messages = [];
    if (newComment.value === '' || newComment.value == null) {
        messages.push('You cannot submit an empty comment')
    }
    
    if (messages.length > 0) {
           errorElement.innerText = messages.join(', ');
    }
    else {
        
    }

}


// remove comment
function removeComment(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this comment?')) {
            let li = e.target.parentElement;
            commentList.removeChild(li);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    /* font-family: 'Kumar One', cursive; */
    font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: rgb(68, 139, 66);

}

header h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

form {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-control {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumar+One&family=Mukta:wght@200;400&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="text-white p-4 mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>Adding items</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h2 class="title">Add a comment</h2>
            <form class="form-inline col-3 row" id="form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comment">
                <div id="error" class="text-danger"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>   
            <h2 class="title">All comments</h2>
            <ul id="allComments" class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">comment 1 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">comment 2 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">comment 3 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">comment 4 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
              </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following validation at the top of the addComment and return if you find comment is empty so the next statements do not execute.

```
if (newComment.value === '' || newComment.value == null) {
    messages.push('You cannot submit an empty comment')

    // Add return to exit from function
    return;
}
```

Comment: The return belongs in the `if (messages.length > 0) { errorElement.innerText = messages.join(', '); return } ... rest of code ...`